# How do i provide the PriceBook2Id on Order object using Sales Force phptoolkit?

Tags: php, salesforce, toolkit

I'm using PHP Toolkit for Sales Force, and it's been working great, except when i try to Create an order.

The error i receive is:

```
[message] => Order: bad field names on insert/update call: Pricebook2Id
```

Where my object field and value are:

```
$orderObj->Pricebook2Id               = '01s4T0000027uumQAA';
```

---- EDIT

For those imagining the ID is wrong, when i query for pricelists on Sales Force, i receive the following in the response:

```
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Id] => 01s4T0000027uumQAA
        [CreatedById] => 0054T000000tM8jQAE
        [CreatedDate] => 2020-02-10T15:03:33.000Z
        [Description] => Produtos Scientific
        [IsActive] => 1
        [IsDeleted] => 
        [IsStandard] => 
        [LastModifiedById] => 0054T000000tM8jQAE
        [LastModifiedDate] => 2020-02-10T15:19:20.000Z
        [Name] => Produtos SST
        [SystemModstamp] => 2020-02-10T15:19:20.000Z
    )
```

There's no information anywhere about this problem, has anyone faced this before?

Answer (score 0):

Turn out this isn't a code or permission problem, it's a validation problem from the WSDL.

If you find yourself in this kind of error with Sales Force, generate and update your WSDL as stated in:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_steps_generate_wsdl.htm

This should solve your field differences problems.

At leats it did for me. Thanks for all that looked in this question. Hope it helps.